# Use MsgBox to open form to new record or delete record from continuous form if the record does not already exist

Tags: vba, ms-access, custom-error-handling

I have a form with a continuous subform that is used to "check out" items. If an item is entered that is not currently in the `items` table, an error fires.

I would like to create a custom `msgbox` that will allow the user to select the next action; either open a form to enter the new item (along with a number of details about the item) or to delete the row.

I have been able to fire the `msgbox` code and successfully open the form to enter a new item, but I cannot get the row to delete from the subform OR use `SetProperty` to return the value to `null`.

Here is the current code to launch the `MsgBox` which is triggered BeforeUpdate, OnError from the control in question.

```vb
Function MsgBox_NewAsset()

    MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("The Asset Number you entered is not in the system. Would you like to enter this as a new asset?", 4 + vbQuestion, "New Asset?")

    If MsgBoxResult = 6 Then
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Asset Details", , , "AssetID=0"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    Else
    DoCmd.SetProperty("AssetID",acPropertyValue,"")
    End If

End Function
```

When setting the `SetProperty` command using:

```
DoCmd.SetProperty("AssetID",acPropertyValue,"")
```

I get a compile error:

> Expected: =

I'm relatively new to VBA, so not entirely sure what this indicates.

Comment: If you want to add items 'on the fly' during data entry, use combobox NotInList event. Common topic and many examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access Combobox not taking a value after requery shows value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326791/ms-access-combobox-not-taking-a-value-after-requery-shows-value)

Comment: To clarify, we are using a barcode scanner for entry of data into the control.

Comment: Should still be able to use a combobox and NotInList event. If the entered (scanned or typed) value is not item in combobox list, NotInList should trigger. Combobox LimitToList property must be set to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo` rather than `DoCmd.SetProperty(...)`

The form is sitting on an uncommitted, new record that can't be committed. To roll it back, use Undo.

Comment: I gave this a try and it was no successful. If by "uncommitted" you mean that no ID has been assigned to the row that is untrue as an ID appears in my ID field when I tab to the next field. Also, even after entering the asset and running a requery, I get an error that the database "cannot find a record in table assets with key matching fields assetID. Shouldn't the requery update the subform?

Comment: Is your ID an Access AutoNumber? If it is, that shouldn't matter. In my tests on this with manually inserting a row in a subform, the AutoNumber value will show the next available number, but the row is still not committed to the table yet. Pressing the ESC key (manual equivalent of `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo`) rolls back the row and "loses" the AutoNumber value.